# how to read webapi(CORS) response header values using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

I am tring to read some values from response header of webapi(cors). The actual issue i am facing is, I can see value in response header using fiddler or developer tools Network tab-> responseheader. When i use the below snippet to get the header value. i am getting null.

```
header("mykeyname")
```

Note: I can retrieve the values in IE but not in chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Only a limited number of headers [are exposed on a CORS response](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header) by default. This won't include any custom ones you added.

You can add more by specifying their names in [the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-response-cors-exposed-header-name-list).